# pass data to dialer in android

Tags: android

I want to launch the dialer with custom nuber but without the call (the user will have to press the call button in order to make the call).
How can i do that?
I only found how to call directly using `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.

Thanks.

Comment: ravi, try to use `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                      Uri.parse("tel://13800138000"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you register for the same Intents as some other application (for example the system build-in dialer) the OS should detect that there's more than one applications which can handle the Intent and will present the user with application chooser dialog. Here's an [example](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&biw=1920&bih=933&tbm=isch&tbnid=IA6lWsBhMcZ18M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/browser-chooser_lpnz.html&docid=mw1zA0dD02h9JM&imgurl=http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/browser-chooser-01-2.jpg&w=320&h=569&ei=vWhwT7SPF4nm4QSPyv2_Ag&zoom=1) with browser apps. This dialog is presented by the OS, so you only have to register and listen to all Intents, and have the right permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml file.